# How to add a new IDL to redhawksdr

Tags: redhawksdr

I would like to add a new IDL file to a Redhawk SDR project using the IDE, but I am unable to find any documentation on how to do this.  I have created a new SCA IDL project and added the IDL file.  It seems to compile and generate the .h file, but how do I get it to generate the Servant and Client .h files and then include them in my Component Project?  Also, when I generate the Servant side .h is it possible to generate a template impl file?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure it is possible to install the IDL project from the IDE.  One way to do this is to go to the IDL project directory and run:

```
$ ./reconf
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Note: If the user does not have write permission to the $OSSIEHOME directory, the install command will have to be run as root:

```
$ sudo make install
```

This will build and install your IDLs and IDL libraries into $OSSIEHOME.  Once that has been done, the IDE should find your new IDL and allow you to add ports to a component or device with this IDL.  Since REDHAWK doesn't know anything specific about your IDL the code generation obviously will only be stubs.